# error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7Application" task could not be loaded from the assembly MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Iis7.dll

Tags: c#, msbuild

Receiving this error when trying to build my application using msbuild:

```
error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7Application" task could not be loaded from the assembly MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Iis7.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [17:37:46] [Step 1/1]
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, had thought the problem was with MSBuild extension pack, but it turned out that I need to add IIS:

[image]